# how to set different sessions for user and admin | CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-4

hello i am working on a project where user and admin have different logins
I want to set different sessions for user and admin
here is I how set admin session

```
$this->session->set('adminData', [
            'id'            => $teacher['id'],
            'name'          => $teacher['name'],
            'email'         => $teacher['email'],
            'new_email'     => $teacher['new_email']
        ]);
```

user's session data as follows

```
$this->session->set('userData', [
                'id'            => $teacher['id'],
                'name'          => $teacher['name'],
                'email'         => $teacher['email'],
                'new_email'     => $teacher['new_email']
            ]);
```

but when validating user

```
if ($this->session->isLoggedIn) {
            return redirect()->to('admin');
        }
```

the only problem I am facing that either I can login as admin or user not both
when I try to login as user when I am already logged as admin, it redirects me to user/account.

Is there any method that i can set **isAdminLoggedIn** for admin and can use **isLoggedIn** for user?

Comment: Instead of overcomplicating yourself with this, why not turn this into a permission-based approach? single log-in routine but each user may or may not have an "admin" permission which, when present, enables admin functionality?

Comment: @JavierLarroulet actually i have to customize everything based on user and admin group . and there are factors also. so i chose to go with this approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set isAdminLoggedIn before or after adminData.

```
$this->session->set('isAdminLoggedIn', true);
```

and can destroy the session when you logged out

```
$this->session->remove(['isAdminLoggedIn']);
```

or together with

```
$this->session->remove(['isAdminLoggedIn', 'adminData']);
```